# Wi-Fi chokes up, where is the problem?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have a problem regarding network.
Currently I have 2 devices:

- Airport Extreeme (soft 7.5.2)
- Linksys WRT610Nv2 with DD-WRT v24-sp2 (08/07/10) mega - build 14896

Linksys works as main device and Airport is connected by cable to Linksys to lower wi-fi connections to single device. Most of the time there is 15 connections to Linksys (90% imac's)
All works quite ok for 95% of the time, but sometimes (few times a day) everything "chokes up" (even with 5-7 connections).

To enter website you have to refresh page 30 times, or wait 10-15 minutes till everything will get back to normal (of course it stops working for all type connections not only HTTP), there is no problem with active stream connections, for example with a download.  There is strict no-torrent policy or any other p2p apps. It's not related with the internet provider (checked with second connection to the first provider switch).

Here is a screenshot from Linksys "while choke", all seems to be fine.

[image]

Is there some configurations that can be responsible for this?

Comment: is that not a lot of clients for one device? I would have thought it capabilities were going to max out at ~10. Would it be possible to use one, and added a new computer every couple of minutes and see what happens?

Comment: problem sometimes exists with even 6 connections, we tried disconnecting devices while "choke" but without any result.

Comment: Does this happen to occur during usage of any other particular RF-emitting devices?  Common examples would be wireless (not cellular) phones, microwaves, baby monitors.  Some other high-energy appliances may also be unintentional emitters depending on their vintage and the wiring in your home.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked for other devices on the same chanel nearby?  Site survey tool will help with this.

Are there any clinets downloading large amounts of data?  Streaming perhaps?

Any chance you have a Skype user in Supernode mode?  Had this happen to me and router became very unresponsive at times.